# How do I make a line invisible in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to do this instead of doing subsets so that my confidence intervals reflect all of the data. (I'm plotting lines one by one on a powerpoint.)

Basically, I need to just have one line be completely invisible.

I've tried

```
scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "transparent"))
```

which seems to do the trick, unless the transparent line overlaps another, in which case it makes it lighter. "none" and "invisible" are not defined color values in R. Advice?

Thanks!

Comment: can we have a **reproducible example** please?

Comment: it seems to me that geom_blank would be more suitable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify `NA` as a color if you just don't want something plotted:

```
values = c("black", NA)
```

Comment: Transparent is a color that it lets me specify. :) But NA is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm. For me, this just results in the lines being gray instead. "transparent" works great, though! Maybe this is because it's been 8 years. So just letting others know.